# How to get records on the basis of date in grails

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

[image]

I am facing some little issues related to date.Actually I am using grails 2.3.7 and try to find records on the basis of date range. Suppose i want to get all records of date 26-11-2014.

So i am using this approach finally.

```
  String fromDate="2014-12-03";
  String toDate="2014-12-04";

  SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

  Date d1 = df1.parse(fromDate);
  Date d2 = df1.parse(toDate);

  Order?.executeQuery("select orderDate from Order where orderDate between ? and ? ",[d1,d2]);
```

And result is

```
  [2014-12-03 10:27:23.0, 2014-12-03 10:30:53.0, 2014-12-03 10:32:30.0]
```

Actually 4 records of 03-12-2014 but we got only 3.

The same thing apply on 2014-11-27 to 2014-11-28

And the result is

```
  [2014-11-27 10:52:56.0, 2014-11-27 13:42:16.0, 2014-11-27 14:44:05.0, 2014-11-27 15:47:36.0,     
  2014-11-27 15:51:36.0, 2014-11-27 16:10:17.0, 2014-11-27 18:01:08.0, 2014-11-27 18:07:47.0,   
  2014-11-27 18:30:54.0, 2014-11-27 18:34:06.0, 2014-11-27 18:40:35.0]
```

Actually 13 records of 27-11-2014 but we got only 11.

Please help me.

I got stuck here.

Comment: did you check for the timings ?

Comment: can you please describe what timing is

Comment: when you are giving between clause check for the whole date format . like  you are providing `2014-12-04`but what it is giving something like this or something else `2014-12-04 12:00:00:000`

Comment: Yes I checked too like SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS")

Comment: and fromDate and toDate values copy from datatable

Comment: so can be possible it is hiding records after 12...

Comment: I don't know.I tried every possible solution as I felt would be

Comment: try to pass whole time with input like `2014-12-04 00:00:00` and end date will be `2014-12-04 24:00:00`

Comment: nothing I got result is empty.

Comment: what the reason behind this please tell me

Comment: will have to check it first'

Comment: ok any other solution as think should be

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the time part of the dates.

You can do the following to retrieve all the rows with orderDate = 2014-12-03:

```
String fromDate="2014-12-03 00:00:00"
String toDate="2014-12-03 23:59:59"
SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
Date d1 = df1.parse(fromDate)
Date d2 = df1.parse(toDate)
Order?.executeQuery("select orderDate from Order where orderDate between ? and ? ",[d1,d2]);
```

you can also use Date.clearTime() to remove the time of the dates.

Comment: Thanks for help ChrisN. The same approach I followed. And it is working fine.

Comment: I need to ask one thing about exportService. I am going to export Order Date column but It writes in file MM:ss instead of complete Date with timestamp. Can you help me.

Comment: when you say export, does it mean that you are using a plugin to write a CSV or other kind of file? If so what's the plugin? Can you share the piece of code that renders the output so I can help you with this issue

Comment: I understand it's been over a year, but do you recall why you put a null-safe operator(`?`) on the `Order` domain in your example?

Answer (score 0):

There is little mistake.As I did yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS 
 while it should be yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: POHH you said correct timeStamp should be 00:00:00 to 24-00:00